# Do "I saw a dream" and "I had a dream" meant the same thing?

Tags: meaning, differences, word-usage

Which of these two is more appropriate:

1. I saw a dream.
2. I had a dream.

Is there any difference between them?

Comment: You had a dream and you saw something funny in that dream, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

The usual idioms are ***I had a dream***, or ***I saw in a dream*** (e.g.the coronation of Donald Trump as King of America).

We wouldn't say *I saw a dream*. Some abstract nouns can be the object of *see* used metaphorically e.g. *I saw happiness*, but *a dream* like *a thought* is not one of them.